# How to use the path name of the URL to fetch data in Next.js 14?

Tags: typescript, next.js, graphql, aws-amplify, next.js14

I am working on a Next.js 14 project with TypeScript and creating a blog using AWS Amplify Gen 2 and GraphQL. In my application, I need to retrieve specific data based on the path name of the URL. Here's what I have so far:

I'm using a component named Article:

```js
'use client';
import { usePathname } from "next/navigation";

export default function Article() {
    const slug = usePathname().split('/').pop();
    return slug;
}
```

I have a page.tsx file under app/articles/[slug]:

```js
import type { Schema } from '@/amplify/data/resource';
import { generateClient } from 'aws-amplify/data';
import Article from '@/components/article/article';

const client = generateClient<Schema>();

async function fetchPosts() {
    const { data: posts } = await client.models.Posts.list();
    return posts;
}

export default async function ArticlePage() {
    const posts = await fetchPosts();
    return (
        // I need to return the posts that match the slug value in the URL path
    );
}
```

I want to modify ArticlePage so that it fetches and returns the posts that match the slug value from the URL path. How can I achieve this?

I'm using Next.js 14 and TypeScript.
The `client.models.Posts.list()` function retrieves all the posts, and I need to filter them based on the slug value from the URL path.

EDIT:

This code below does the trick, but instead of a String, I need it to be the URL path /articles/my-first-post or /articles/my-second-post.

```js
import type { Schema } from '@/amplify/data/resource';
import { generateClient } from 'aws-amplify/data';

const client = generateClient<Schema>();

async function fetchPosts() {
    const { data: posts, errors } = await client.models.Posts.list();
    return posts;
}

export default async function Article() {
    const slug = 'my-first-post';
    const posts = await fetchPosts();
    const filteredPosts = posts.filter(post => post.slug === slug);

    return (
        <div>
            {filteredPosts.map(post => (
                <div key={post.createdAt}>
                    <h2>{post.title}</h2>
                    <p>{new Date(post.createdAt).toLocaleDateString()}</p>
                    <p>{post.content}</p>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
async function fetchPosts(slug) {
    const { data: posts } = await client.models.Posts.list();
    return posts.filter((p) => p.id === slug); // or whatever you need to match
}

export default async function ArticlePage({ params }: { params: { slug: string } }) {
    const posts = await fetchPosts(params.slug);
    return (
        ...
    );
}
```

probably would do the trick. You don't need the code from `Article` component then.

However, I would probably do the filtering inside with `client.models.Posts.list(slug)` and fetch only the relevant ones. It would be more efficient.

Comment: Whenever I try to add anything inside the parentheses of ArticlePage(), I get this error: "Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'list')." The issue doesn't seem to be related to the data because I have another page that's receiving the same data but uses the function without anything inside the parentheses.

Comment: The error seems to say that `Posts` is undefined in `client.model.Posts.list()`. there is not enough information to know why that would happen.

Comment: It appears this only works when the function is asynchronous. I tried to do exactly the same as it is in the documentation, but it gives this error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'list')` https://docs.amplify.aws/gen2/start/quickstart/nextjs-pages-router/

Comment: Your code actually worked :) I just replaced `(p) => p.id === slug` with `(p) => post.slug === slug`. Thank you very much!